# Site column validation - not allow to use slash / backslash / questionmark / \?

Tags: column, site-column, validation

Got a script that creates new site collection based on a template  (clone site collection). Problem is that some users type in slash / backslash in the title site column, that makes the url wrong.

Is there a way to use Column Validation to validate the input. I don't want the users to write characters that screw up the url, like slash, backslash, questionmark in the title column.

I've tried to put in RegEx without any luck :( 
[RegularExpression(@"^[^\/]*$")]

Answer (score 0):

Just include the / in the character class. But since you are using / as the regex delimiter you need to escape it as well as /. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I've tried as many variations of slash `/` as I can come up with:

- `\2F`
- `\002F`
- `%2F`
- `&#2F;`
- `0x2F`
- ...and more

We simply cannot use these characters in site column names if want to use them in this kind of custom validation.